# I'm having trouble finding these commands to run in a batch file?

Tags: scripting, batch, command-line-interface

I want a batch file to pull information from the first line of a text file (notepad), use that information to add information to a DNS server, and then delete it. I'm thinking if I create a loop, I can make it go all the way through the text file, using the first line of information to add to the DNS server and then deleting the first line before starting a loop. For example... The batch file would be

```
@echo off
:start
dnscmd "mydns" /zoneadd (need to know the command from here to add the FQDN from the text file)
::(Need to know the command here to delete the first line of the text file and save the file)
goto start
```

The text file reads

```
Siteno1.com
Siteno2.com
Siteno3.com
```

So I want it to add `Siteno1.com` to the dns, then delete it, start at the beginning of the text file, and add `Siteno2.com` to the dns, delete it, and start from the beginning again until the text file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in primitive in `CMD.EXE` to delete lines from text files. I suspect you'd find utility in the `for` command.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (textfile.txt) do echo dmscmd "mydns" /zoneadd %%i
```

That will iterate thru all the lines in `textfile.txt` displaying the example `dnscmd` command-line for each line of the file. (Obviously, remove the `echo` to have it actually execute commands).

The syntax for `for` is somewhat arcane. When you use `for` at a bare command-prompt you don't double `%%` the environment variables. I find `for` to be incredibly handy and use it on a daily basis (but, then, I'm also at the command-prompt on a daily basis, too).

Comment: That was VERY helpful! One more thing I need though, if you can add it to the command above, I need each of the sites being added to the Forward Lookup Zones to have a loopback Host added (done in the GUI by right clicking in the window and selecting New Host (A) and inputting 127.0.0.1 as the IP Address)  what I have so far on the CMD is:

for /f %i in (MasterTest.txt) do dnscmd 140.21.20.2 /zoneadd %i

That adds it to the dns but doesn't input the loopback. :) if you could help me with that I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Look at my answer to your other question.